# How to successfully send an email in a contact form through CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, contact-form

I have set up my controller and my contact form all set up. But when I click "Submit" on my contact page, I receive no errors but I receive no email. Can anyone help me figure out why I am not actually receiving the email? I appreciate any help. Here is my code for the controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->template->build('home');
    }

    public function email() {
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $phone_number = $this->input->post('phone_number');
        $message = $this->input->post('message');
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from($email, 'Your Name');
        $this->email->to('anish@develop.io');
        $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
        $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');
        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message(
          'My name is'.$name.', Im testing this email class. My email is '.$email. '. My Phone number is '.$phone_number.
         ' This is my message '.$message. ' Thanks!!'
         );
        $this->email->send();
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        $this->template->build('home');
    }
}
```

And here is my code for my contact page view:

```
<div class="inner-content" id="contact-content">

  <title>CSS3 Contact Form</title>
  <div id="contact">
    <h1>Send an email</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/home/email">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
        <label for="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send message">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First please make sure you have setup smtp server to send email correctly.

Comment: What does the debugger echo out?

Comment: The output is exactly this:
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail

From: "Your Name" 
Return-Path: 
Cc: another@another-example.com
Bcc: them@their-example.com
Reply-To: "dfgrfgh@gd.com" 
X-Sender: dfgrfgh@gd.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <51b0de09bea00@gd.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Email_Test?=
My name isdfdfdf, Im testing this email class. My email is dfgrfgh@gd.com.
My Phone number is This is my message dfdfdfdfdfsdafsafsdfsfdsfdsfsdf
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable `php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini` file and try using gmail. The answer of Pascal Spruit or Omade will work. Don't forget to restart you local server after editing in `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'yourname@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'yourpassword',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->from('youremail@gmail.com', 'Jodie');
$this->email->to('toemail@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('testing email');
$this->email->message('This shows the email worked');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps try to configure email class first

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
```

Try to add this code around email->send() function to see what is the response

Change  `$this->email->send();` To

```
if ( ! $this->email->send())
{
    echo 'Some error in sending email';
}
```

If the error string doesn't echo then problem is not with CI, its probably with mail server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I am not receiving  any output. When I click "submit", the Firefox page appears stating: 
Document Expired
This document is no longer available.
The requested document is not available in Firefox's cache.

Comment: Try sending email to gmail. Some servers might be blocking the test emails.

Comment: Try this

    mail('abc@example.com', 'test email', 'this is a test');

If this doesn't work then check your SMTP settings in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Try using gmail

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'someuser@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );

$this->load->library('email', config);
$this->email->from('email@gmail.com', 'George');
$this->email->to('email@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('hey this is an email');
$this->email->message('this is the content of the email');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck with this same problem but I am figure out one thing every thing going on successfully on gmail but only email not goes.

if I am send `$email = $this->input->post('useremail');`that is not goes on gmail. It's show mail send successfully or what ever you pass on "if" condition but mail not come in mail box. But if I am pass any thing else like name phone password or any thing, that's all goes successfully.
Is there any restriction in CI or php for email.
Because I am send html content successfully on server but only email not goes.
One more thing every thing send including email but through local-host but I am up my website on hostinger and config everything and everything going great but just email not pass on form,

If any one have any idea about this- how to include email on contact form, then pleas shear your knowledge with me.

Comment: I am not yet get full solution but if you want to check then comment your  $email = $this->input->post('email'); and also remove form message portion, then check, my be you get mail on your email box.