# codeigniter - email class - registration after submission

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, email

made a simple submission user form email & city data saved in database, now I need to add in this form after submission of data system generate auto email on user address but with mentioned variable i use one variable called `$lang` if user input is **ar** so send the email in arabic or if user input **en** so send email in english, there is two problems I face dont know how to fix this email class in code for suggestions i share code.

**Email class**

```
public function email() {
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $city = $this->input->post('city');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from('noreply@abc.com', 'Halalat');
    $this->email->to('$emai');
    $this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
    $this->email->message( 'Thankyou for submission' );
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

**user.php in controller**

```
<?php 

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('user_agent');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function create_user() {
        // field name, error message, validation rules
        $lang = $this->input->post("lang");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'trim|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            if ($lang == "en") {
                if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                    $this->load->view('m_english_signup');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $this->load->view('d_english_signup');
                }
                } //if ($this->agent->is_mobile())
            else 
            {
                if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                    $this->load->view('m_arabic_signup');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $this->load->view('d_arabic_signup');
                }
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            if ($query = $this->Users_model->create_member()) {
                if ($lang == "en") {
                    if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                        $this->load->view('m_english_thanks');
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->load->view('d_english_thanks');
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
                        $this->load->view('m_arabic_thanks');
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $this->load->view('d_arabic_thanks');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**users_model.php in model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Users_model extends CI_Model
    {


    function create_member()
    {
            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),                           
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);
            return $insert;


    }//create_member
}
```

Comment: **there is two problems i face** what is the two problems?

Comment: 1- How to implement email class and where.
2- How to manage two language input with email class.

Comment: For 1: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16969572/270037

Comment: @kumar_v Thankyou so much i will try to learn and implement this in code.

Comment: @kumar_v as you mentioned the link i check it guide only the email class and my question is still the same, email function is already ready but i want to know when i submit form this function triger and send email to user, do you know how i triger this email function with submit button.

Comment: After create_member(), you have to send email. For sendng email in CI, you check the user guide.

Comment: if i will already understand this problem then why i ask here sir!

Comment: Where is email code exist? in same controller or some other file?

Comment: i already mention the email function in question

Comment: i need when user submit the data so send email to user only this i need.

Comment: @kumar_v i update email function here and i use this function in controller user.php and now i want to trigger this function when user submit the form.

Comment: sorry formal i was not able to check this before.hope you got the answer :)

Comment: Yes teacher i got it answer and solve this, now try to learn functions & variables of php :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make email sending section as a function in your controller:

```
public function sendUserMail($email)
{
  $this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('noreply@abc.com', 'Halalat');
$this->email->to('$email'); 

$this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
$this->email->message('Testing');   
$this->email->attach('/assests/images/photo1.jpg');
$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

In your action section, add email function call after

```
if ($query = $this->Users_model->create_member()) {
```

like:

```
   $this->sendUserMail($this->input->post("email"));
```

Comment: thankyou so much i add on local server stmp off so i test on international server but i need some changes please guide i add this 
`$config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'someuser@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'password',
        'mailtype'  => 'html',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
    );`

Comment: so config setting i mention in same function ?

Comment: yes. you can. But, email functionality will be used in some other controller also. So just create a `helper` and place this email function in that helper. auto load this helper in your config. So you can use anywhere in the project.

Comment: i m not an expert to make helper i am very new in codeigniter even php too i will try as you guide i will use.

Comment: `Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
From: "Halalat" <fahadvintage@gmail.com>
Return-Path: <fahadvintage@gmail.com>
Reply-To: "fahadvintage@gmail.com" <fahadvintage@gmail.com>
X-Sender: fahadvintage@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <52db84d14d77a@gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Halalat_Newsletter_Subscription?=
Testing`
**not sending email to user email return to my email again with errors**

Comment: but you are getting success message. how?

Comment: [link](http://fahad.myradio.pk) **you visit link just fill up form** email send and in my gmail spam folder msg come but email sending on user provided email id.

Comment: $email not working , this variable not get data from input post properly how can i fix this.

Comment: i fix sending mail for single user.