# CodeIgniter - Refer Url - Saved In Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, refer

i need to save a refer url in database, for example user see an advertise on facebook and click on link when the user comes only database save the url in database for this i make a function but i didn't get exactly of function please suggest.

> welcome.php controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $refer_url =  $this->input->get("refer_url");
    $this->Users_model->refer_data($refer_url);

    if ($this->input->get("lang") =="en"){
        if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
            $this->load->view('m_english_signup');
        }
        else {
            $this->load->view('d_english_signup');
        }
    }

elseif($this->agent->is_mobile())
     {
        $this->load->view('m_arabic_signup');
}
else {
    $this->load->view('d_arabic_signup');
}
}
```

> user_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Users_model extends CI_Model
    {


    function create_member()
    {
            $new_member_insert_data = array(
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'city' => $this->input->post('city'),                           
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert_data);  
        return $insert;


    }   //create_member

    function refer_data($arg)
    {
        $refer_data = array(
                'refer_url' => $arg,                
            );
            $insert = $this->db->insert('refer', $refer_data);  
        return $insert; 

    }   //refer_data

}
```

**Errors**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function refer_data() on a non-object in
>   /home/content/f/a/h/fahadghafoor/html/fahad/application/controllers/welcome.php
>   on line 9

Comment: have you loaded the user_agent library?

Comment: its already loaded because i have two version of websites one for mobile and one for desktop computers so its already loaded.

Comment: do u get o/p from echo ?

Comment: i add this function in model but no result coming thats why i ask is this code correct or whats the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
function refer(){
   $this->load->library('user_agent');
   if ($this->agent->is_referral()) {
      $insert =$this->db->insert('refer', array('refer_url'=>$this->agent->referrer()));    
   }
}
```

**EDIT_1_**

Change in `welcome.php` to: // You forgot load `user_model`

```
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    $this->load->library('user_model');

    $refer_url =  $this->user_agent->referrer();    
    $this->user_model->refer_data($refer_url);
```

Change in `user_model.php` to:

```
    $insert = $this->insert('refer', $refer_data);
```

Comment: i add this in model and test on local server but no result add in database.

Comment: @FormaL add to controller or ,if in the model, change   `$this->db->insert` to `$this->insert`

Comment: @FormaL if you testing locally, remove `$this->agent->is_referral()` always will return false

Comment: your above code i mention in controller and update when i visit web again nothing to show!

Comment: wait then i will upload on int server and check ok

Comment: do `var_dump($this->agent->is_referral() ` and you will see false.Because $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is equal.

Comment: i add code in controller, and i check db but no data enters [link](http://fahad.myradio.pk)

Comment: comment out on time this  `$this->agent->is_referral()` and try . For testing

Comment: @FormaL what fieds in table `refer`?

Comment: @FormaL i update answer,but i dont know what fields in table `refer`

Comment: i mention this code in user.php controller but the main controller is welcome.php without trigger how this function work so i am confused there how i trigger this function, secondly table name i use refer same as column name.

Comment: table name is refer & column name in table is refer_url but still nothing to display.

Comment: @FormaL comment out on time `this $this->agent->is_referral()` ? how are you testing? before inserting did `var_dump($this->agent->agent->referrer())` ?

Comment: not add var_dump i just add your provided code in welcome.php controller only nothing else i do.

Comment: @FormaL check what var_dump returnig

Comment: `function refer(){
   $this->load->library('user_agent');
   if var_dump ($this->agent->is_referral()) {
   $insert =$this->db->insert('refer', array('refer_url'=>$this->agent->referrer()));    
   }
    }`

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in /home/content/f/a/h/fahadghafoor/html/fahad/application/controllers/welcome.php on line 30`

Comment: @FormaL its syntax error. Check any '('. I cannot check your code on syntax errors :)

Comment: function refer(){ 
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
    var_dump($this->agent->referrer());
    $insert =$this->db->insert('refer', array('refer_url'=>$this->agent->referrer()));
}

Comment: as you provide the code same as i use in welcome.php controller and now i visit the web but database table is empty, even i also provide a  link to you. [link](http://fahad.myradio.pk)

Comment: @FormaL how u are testing? whar var_dump return?

Comment: you provide code i only put this code in controller file welcome.php and upload it nothing else i do as i told you earlier i dont know too much of CI just a beginner.

Comment: insert into Contoller in method `init` this `$this->refer();`. Call this method on initialization

Comment: I Updated my post please review

Comment: `An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: users_model`
i update and now this error coming i check users_model.php but this error shows.

Comment: rename class model to `User_model`

Comment: as you said rename file i already rename but you load from library and this is in model how its load? and the same error again.

Comment: `Unable to load the requested class: user_model`

Comment: Please Check link , need suggestions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201276/codeigniter-email-class-registration-after-submission)

Comment: @FormaL sorry, i didnt understand.